# Workbook.SaveAs method for excel 2000

Tags: c#, save-as, excel-2000

I have an application created on c# that opens a workbook then populate it with data then it will be saveas with a new file name. The problem is my application crashes when the PC is using excel 2000 and it works just fine for higher version of microsoft excel.I believe that excel 2000 has only 10 arguments while 2003 and later have 12 arguments but i can't find the correct arguments for excel 2000. This is the code that i am using right now. thanks

```
Workbook.SaveAs("filename", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
          Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
          Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: maybe reading this might give you an idea https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36.aspx#

Comment: Tried using Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@"filename", 
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange); but still cant open it excel 2000. any method on saving workbooks that support excel 2000?

Comment: Check this out :) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306023